# Setting an environment variable in Windows 10: gPodder

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, podcasts

I have just installed the podcast client gPodder (https://gpodder.github.io/).

I am trying to change the default download directory, and the manual indicates that you set the environment variable GPODDER_DOWNLOAD_DIR to the location of the download folder that you wish to specify.

I Have opened the command line tool and entered

`set GPODDER_DOWNLOAD_DIR=C:\~\Downloads`.

This doesn't work and I really have no idea what I should be doing. I'm sure it's very simple but any help would be much appreciated.

The relevent section of the gPodder user manual is here: https://gpodder.github.io/docs/user-manual.html#changing-the-downloads-folder-location-and-the-gpodder-home-folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables created within a CMD session are local to that session and are not persistent; i.e. disappear after CMD closes.

[image: CMD variable out of scope]

You need to create an *environment* variable that all applications can share:

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>Pause</kbd> to open the *System* dialog.
- Select *Advanced system settings*.
- In the *System Properties* dialog, select *Environment Variables...*.

[image: Environment Variables...]

- In the *Environment Variables* dialog, you can create *User* variables,which only the current user's applications can access, and *System* variables, which are shared by all users. If you're the only one needing gPodder, then you can create a new *User* variable for  `GPODDER_DOWNLOAD_DIR`, otherwise make a new *System* variable. This will persist even after rebooting Windows.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed thank you very much!